# How to setup Git

Tags: git, svn

I have been appointed the task to set up a GIT repository by my manager.
Unfortunately I have no experience with GIT.

A lot of the tutorials use GitHub which is not what I want or do not suit my needs.

The scenario:

-The developers in the team will have their own local repositories.

-A remote repository that will be on a another windows machine (via remote login). If this is not possible then remote repository can be on a shared drive.

-All the developers should be able to push/pull

-Ideally the remote repository will be one repository will all the projects (like SVN) and not individual repositories for each project

-New developers that join the team should be able to pull from the remote repository and be able to download all the teams projects. (like in SVN)

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Start by reading the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), then find tutorials or articles for any specific questions (or come back with something more specific to ask here). I think what you are currently asking is too broad  to answer well in this format.

Comment: You **really** need to learn how git operates before you proceed. There are several red flags in your description here that you won't understand the consequences of until much later in the process. For instance, it is **not** recommended throwing all the projects into one big repository. Git operates on a whole-repository level and you'll have merges en mass if you do parallel development on multiple unrelated projects in one repository.

Comment: You should use the network share method, unless you can set up a proper hosting system, like gitlab, or use a cloud based hosting partner (github, bitbucket, etc.). One big difference between using a proper hosting system vs. just a network share is that it is often **much** easier setting up per-branch access with a proper hosting system (ie. "nobody is allowed to push into master other than X or Y"). Quite often, such hosting applications also provide "pull request" functionality, something which you won't get with just the file share route.

Comment: But I support @crashmstr's comment. This topic is **far** too broad to be answered on a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow because most likely, any "answer" you would get will just provoke further questions. This is more of a workshop/discussion than it is a Q&A.

Comment: By the way, on the point of "one repo or many" - as this is one that trips people up quickly: The problem here is linguistic. People are used to maintaining one thing that SVN calls a repository, and they imagine maintaining one for each project, and they think "what a pain".  But what git calls a repository *is not analogous* to what SVN calls a repository.  There is nothing in git itself that corresponds to a SVN repo; rather the server under which you host git repos is like a SVN repo, and the git repos are like projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your questions bit by bit:

> I have been appointed the task to set up a GIT repository by my manager. Unfortunately I have no experience with GIT.

Is there anyone around that has? It would be really great to let them do it, or at least let them guide you through it. Setting up the repository when a team starts out with `git` can either make everything a breeze, or lead to endless pain in the future. Getting `git` to run will be easy, but deciding a repository strategy not so much.

> The developers in the team will have their own local repositories.

Yup, that is the way of distributed VCSses.

> A remote repository that will be on a another windows machine (via remote login). If this is not possible then remote repository can be on a shared drive.

You do not want the remote on a shared drive, no. This will get you into all kinds of trouble; shared drives are notoriously bad with file locking, concurrent access and all that. Remote login is the way to go.

A quick google for "git server windows" turns out that you can just use the `git over ssh` variant (which is the usual bare-bones solution on Unix servers) on Windows as well. The hard part seems to be setting up the `ssh` server, after that, `git` should be a breeze. As this is only tangential to this question, I'd ask you to google for yourself, the first few hits are all fine.

Do you have some Unix server around? Then it would be most trivial to use that one.

> All the developers should be able to push/pull

Sure, that's the way DVCSses work.

> Ideally the remote repository will be one repository will all the projects (like SVN) and not individual repositories for each project

*No.* You absolutely do not want that. This makes no sense whatsoever, except in very specific circumstances, if you know really well what you are doing. `git` is all about not being used like that.

> New developers that join the team should be able to pull from the remote repository and be able to download all the teams projects. (like in SVN)

You mean at once? If that is so important for you, then you can, after creating individual repositories, create a "master repository" which contains sub-modules for each of the other ones. Then they can in fact work a little like in SVN, though I would really, really suggest not to do so, as this can be quite an advanced topic. While it seems simple on the surface, there are plenty of pitfalls.

I read between the lines that there is either some resistance against the switch from `svn` to `git` in your team, or that you are assuming that "doing it like in `svn`" will somehow make it easier. That is not so. `git` is fundamentally different from `svn`. You (as a team) will do yourself a huge disservice by using `git` just like `svn` and will reap none of its benefits that way (or it will actually simply be impossible to do even simple branching/merging schemes).

Also, I would *really* suggest that you either make yourself a `git` expert first (by a lot of reading, and trial&error in a play environment), or find a `git` expert in your company before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

When someone keeps saying "it needs to work like SVN" (they used to say "it needs to work like CVS"), they are setting themselves up for years of disappointment.  The fact is, git is not SVN.

A repo in git should represent a project.  If you really *must* have one super-repo that pulls everything, I'd look into submodules or subtrees so that each project can still have its own repository.  I don't recommend even that.

There are many options for how to set up a remote repo.  You can put them on a windows server, typically behind an HTTP server.  You can use any number of server-side products that host the repo more intelligently.  If your org has a modern version TFS, it does a pretty good job serving git repos.  A shared drive will also certainly work, but may have some inefficiencies.

When you say the developers will "have a repo" -- well, yes, that's pretty much mandatory with git.  But more than that, there should be no reason a developer couldn't create additional instances (clones) of any repo they want, at will.  Again, that's the nature of git.

If you learn to deal with git on its terms rather than trying to make it "feel like" SVN, you will probably have a very pleasant experience with it and find it more flexible and powerful than SVN ever was for you.  If you try to treat it like SVN, you'll become one of those people who always claim that git somehow lost their data.